# Subtracting from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that contains stock of tyres the nodes look like this

```
<Stock>
  <Tyre>
    <Manufacturer>Yokohama</Manufacturer>
    <Quantity>500</Quantity>
  </Tyre>
</Stock>
```

On another form I have an order form where you can select the manufacturer of tyre in a textbox or a comboBox drop down, and I would like to enter an amount in a textbox and it will subtract from and update the quantity node.

Would I have to do a for each loop and look through each tyre manufacturer node for the name entered into the textbox?

```
foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("Stock/Tyre"))
{
    Stock st = new Stock();
    st.manufacturer = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Manufacturer ").InnerText;
    //???
}
```

Where to comment with the ? is where I am stuck how would I get it to subtract the value in the textbox from the stock quantity in the xml file.

Should I be doing it this way or is this completely wrong?

Comment: double.Parse(xNode.SelectSingleNode("Quantity").InnerText) - double.Parse(TextBox.Text)

Comment: But i think iterating through all items to just update one element is a bad approach. Read about LinQ to xml

Comment: Didn't you ask the exact same thing a few days ago? Seems very known to me ..

Comment: I did, my question vanished when I checked this morning Patrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done much more easily and elegant using LINQ to XML:

```
var fileName = @"c:\test.xml";
var manufacturer = "Yokohama";
var amount = 100;

var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var node = doc.XPathSelectElements("Stock/Tyre/Manufacturer")
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == manufacturer);
if (node != null)
{
    var valueNode = node.Parent.XPathSelectElement("Quantity");
    if (valueNode != null)
        valueNode.SetValue(Convert.ToInt32(valueNode.Value)  - amount);
}

doc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Input Andy I have been looking at LinQ and your answer helps me a great deal. many Thanks

Comment: @Topher Just add `using System.Xml.XPath` to your code. `XPathSelectElements` is an extension method defined in that namespace.